# What is the expected result of subscripting a range?

Tags: swift

I can't find any documentation explaining what subscripting a range is supposed to do. I'd expect it to yield the nth value of the range, but it seems to return the subscripted value, itself.

```
let range = 10...20
let valueFromRange = range[2]
```

In this case, I'd expect `valueFromRange` to equal `12`, but it's equal to `2`. This seems to be the case for all ranges (or, at least all ranges of type `Range<Int>` and `Range<Double>`).

Is this the value I'm supposed to get? Besides defying what I think is probably the commonly expected behavior, this behavior is also useless.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert the range to an `Array` if you want to subscript it like that:

```
let range = Array(10..20)
range[2] // returns 12
```

While you can add `range.startIndex` and subscript directly for this particular range, you can't subscript strided ranges at all without converting them:

```
let range = (10..20).by(3)
range[2] // error: 'StridedRangeGenerator<Int>' does not have a member named 'subscript'
```

Answer (score 0):

The n-element in a range is the `range.startIndex + n` element.
So to get what you are looking for you should use:

```
let valueFromRange = range[range.startIndex+2]
```

Which in your case would be `range[12]`

If you want the n-element to have index n, you should convert it to an Array:

```
let rangeConverted = Array(range)
rangeConverted[2] // will return 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `range[subscript]` is probably not really supported. I don't have any hard evidence and I may be wrong, but it seems that a range is something like this:

```
class Range {
  var _startIndex
  var _endIndex
}
```

Now, I'm not sure if there can be non-number ranges. If not, then a index is really a value. So basically `10..20` means that the range starts at 10 and ends at 20. What I'm guessing is that, for a for loop,

```
for i in 10..20 {}
```

is the same as

```
for i = _startIndex; i < _endIndex; i++
```

So perhaps range does not really support subscript, and it's just some inherited subscript from some base class.

Again, no hard evidence, and I don't really find the doc for Range in any reference.. I also think it'd be nice to support subscript, but just my 2c.

Comment: Ranges are structs, not classes, and structs don't support inheritance. Range actually implements subscripting as part of conforming to the `Sliceable` protocol, which has no other methods. It seems like they're maybe… just not done implementing it? Though that raises the question of why they conform to `Sliceable` at all yet.